C++ Concurrency - memory_order_acquire
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
std::vector<int> queue_data;
std::atomic<int> count;

void populate_queue()
{
    unsigned const number_of_items=20;
    queue_data.clear();
    for(unsigned i=0;i<number_of_items;++i)
    {
        queue_data.push_back(i);
    }
    count.store(number_of_items,std::memory_order_release);
}

void consume_queue_items()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int item_index;
        if((item_index=count.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_acquire))<=0)
        {
            wait_for_more_items();
            continue;
        }
        process(queue_data[item_index-1]);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread a(populate_queue);
    std::thread b(consume_queue_items);
    std::thread c(consume_queue_items);
    a.join();
    b.join();
    c.join(); 
}

This is a code snippet from book C++ concurrency in action, section 5.3.4.
Author says that

Without the release sequence rule or memory_order_release on the
fetch_sub operations, there would be nothing to require that the
stores to the queue_data were visible to the second consumer, and you
would have a data race.

I don't understand why do we need to release on fetch_sub to synchronize data stored (ofcourse we need to synchronize count to avoid duplicate processing) but why doesn't 2nd consumer synchronize with release of populate_queue thread?

I'm not sure I understand the question. What changes do you propose be made to the code shown? You seem to be saying that you want memory_order_release both in populate_queue and in consume_queue_items, which doesn't make sense. The title of your post mentions "memory order consume" but the text of the question doesn't talk about consume order at all.

Sorry, my bad for mentioning memory_order_consume. Updated title.
My question is why doesn't 2nd consumer thread synchronize with release of producer? How can their be data race on the aspect that items are not stores.
(I understand there is race on count due to two consumers not synchronizing)
@IgorTandetnik

The point of release/acquire semantics is this: when an atomic is written with release order, that change to the atomic, as well as changes to other shared data updated before the release operation, are made visible to another thread that reads this atomic with acquire order. The point of release/acquire semantics in the example is not just to synchronize access to count, but to make populated queue_data visible to consuming threads. Without release/acquire (or stronger) atomic operations, consumer thread might observe stale state in queue_data

I understand the semantic of release and acquire but my question is to understand why do you need memory_order_release on fetch_sub. Please read the extract below >
Without the release sequence rule or memory_order_release on the fetch_sub operations, there would be nothing to require that the stores to the queue_data were visible to the second consumer, and you would have a data race.


Note here that author specifically says this is fine when there is only one consumer and not fine when there are 2 consumers


I don't understand why do we need to release on fetch_sub

You don't. Notice that the code uses an acquire and says that this is okay.

why doesn't 2nd consumer synchronize with release of populate_queue thread?

It does.
Notice what your quote from the book says (emphasis mine):

Without the release sequence rule or memory_order_release on the fetch_sub operations,

What does the release sequence rule say, quoted from the standard:

A release sequence headed by a release operation A on an atomic object M is a maximal contiguous sub-sequence of side effects in the modification order of M , where the first operation is A, and every subsequent operation is an atomic read-modify-write operation

Therefore you have a release sequence of the form producer -> consumer 1 -> consumer 2 -> … (or consumer 2 -> consumer 1, if consumer 2 wins the race). The point is that consumer 1 overwriting the value of count does not break the release sequence and therefore consumer 2 still synchronizes with the producer, as explained here in the standard:

An atomic operation A that performs a release operation on an atomic object M synchronizes with an atomic operation B that performs an acquire operation on M and takes its value from any side effect in the release sequence headed by A.

So the second consumer still synchronizes with the producer even though it takes its value from the first consumer.

Thanks for the detailed answer. One thing is not clear, why is release sequence of form producer -> consumer 1 -> consumer 2.
There doesn't seem any synchronization between consumer 1 and consumer 2, only producer -> consumer 1 and producer -> consumer 2

@Rupa I expanded the answer. consumer 1 and 2 don't synchronize, consumer 1 simply doesn't break the synchronization between consumer 2 and the producer
